# get facebook user id with javascript sdk. And using global?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to use user's facebook id in another functions. I used return but it didn't work. Whats wrong in my code?

```
function get_id(){
    FB.login(function(response) { 
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.api('/me?access_token='+token+'', function(response) {
                    var id = response.id;
                    return id;
                });
            }
    });
    }
    var user_id = get_id();
```

this is an facebook app. And, I used come code with multi friend selector but i want to use user id global.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return results from an async function. Make your function accept a callback instead and continue in there.

```
function get_id(cb) {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api('/me?access_token=' + token + '', function (response) {
                cb(response.id);
            });
        }
    });
}

get_id(function (user_id) {
    console.log(user_id);
});
```

Comment: I know you just copy-pasted his code as a base of your answer, but manual adding token is not necessary (and makes no sense)

Comment: and how can i get return form get_id function?? I need user id in another function.

Comment: You cannot return the value under any circumstances. That "other function" must be called from your callback. You can however store it in a global variable to access it e.g. after clicking a button or doing something else that is guaranteed to happen after the async call has finished.